# git remote -v : url is shown as ssh but it should be https

Tags: github, ssh, https, rsa, public-key

Summary of the problem:

I'm trying to push to a remote repository on Github, but it is giving me this error:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
'192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.*
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Background on what I did:

I added a remote repo as usual by getting the url shown on Github. The command I typed was:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/bowtie/myremote.git`

Then I checked my remote repos by typing `git remote -v` and, even though I added an https url, it shows urls with "ssh" in front of them:

`git remote -v`
`origin  ssh://git@github.com/bowtie/myremote.git (fetch)`
`origin  ssh://git@github.com/bowtie/myremote.git (push)`

Then I tried to push anyway, at which point it gave me the error I mentioned:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112'
to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is it showing ssh even though I added the url as https? I tried changing it using git remote set-url, nothing changed. I removed the URL completely then readded it and it still added the "ssh" to it. I checked the git config file, and the URL is written correctly with https inside it, then why is it showing ssh on the command line?

By the way, I had another remote and when I encountered this problem, I deleted the .git file from the local repo and reinitialised it, then created another remote, thinking maybe the problem was in the remote. But still the problem persisted. I had tried to change from https to ssh before, but I couldn't get the key. Right now, I just want git bash to show me the correct URL without the ssh:// and to push my commits.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git config -l | grep insteadof`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where the problem was. I had previously made a command to replace every https with ssh using insteadOf, which applies to all git operations. I fixed it by fixing the git config --global file.

The command I used was something like this :
`git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

The solution is to edit the config global file by using:
`git config --global --edit` and delete the line manually

I found the problem explained here: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/git-force-to-use-ssh-url-instead-of-https-for-github-com/4384

And I found the solution explained here: https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe